GCP datflow job connecting to a GCP VM instance running an HTTP Server
i have a GCP Dataflow application and i am planning invoking REST commands to a FAST API server running on one of my VM hosts
I am planning for my VM not to expose an external IP address (as i dont want to be hit from the outside)
How can my GCP dataflow connect to my VM?do they need to reside in the same network?
Could anyone pls advise?
Kind  regards
Marco

Hi @user1068378, does this document helpful for you ?

thanks, it worked... had some issues in setting up firewall rules for my VM which sidetracked me for a while, but all is good now
thanks  a lot
